# How to alter transparency by spatial location

Tags: arcmap, cartography, transparency-opacity

I'm trying to create a map that has a all layers within a subject area having 0% transparency (full opaque), while features outside that area (defined by a polygon shapefile) having a reduced transparency of say 50%. The ideal result is a map that has a focus on a specific area, but also shows the surrounding area. I'm working with ArcMap 10.

Similar to [this](http://portlandwindshieldrepair.com/images/Map_OR.jpg) image:

[image]

I tried using the clip feature in the Data Frame properties but its not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Those kinds of images are often drawn by overlaying a mask shapefile *on top* of the others, drawing it in gray with some alpha transparency.  (The mask is the set-theoretic complement of the area of interest and is readily created using geoprocessing operations such as a union.)  This requires no change in any of the layers that make up the map itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to whuber suggestion (using geoprocessing tool) you can create this look by:

1. Create temp polygon shp, and digitize a large feature over all features that you want to mask out.
2. Use the [Erase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/) tool to erase the temp polygon from your AOI layer.
3. The resulting layer, from the erase operation, you can load into ArcMap and give it a transparency.

This method will not mask labels though.  To mask labels you can setup a separate label class (for each feature that has labels) to define those features within and outside your mask.

Comment: We use this method for cartographic masking. A similar option is to use buffer for graduation of zone (boundaries) - delineate boundaries more prominently between states, neighbourhoods etc > http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1116 Example image is http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5219/5385705814_dd346253d6.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:

1. Created big_aoi featureclass
2. Created small_aoi featureclass (the real area of interest in the middle)
3. Unioned the two (but Erase will work better as artwork21 points out), got big_aoi_Union featureclass
4. Deleted the inner polygon from the union to get the donut
5. Set  big_aoi_Union to dark grey with 50% transparency

And I got:

[image]

This could probably all be scripted with arcpy I bet.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS Pro, you can hide features in layer 1 by setting another overlapping layer (layer2) as a 'mask' source. Take this example, I want the shaded green outer polygon to hide the pink polygons it covers, leaving the pink polygon not covered still visible.
[image]

I select the pink polygon layer in the TOC on the left, then in the Appearance ribbon tab I select the drop down 'Masking' menu to tick the check box of the green polygon (this set the green polygon as a mask source).

[image]

No feature editing needed. Just a quick out of the box option which doesn't change the underlying data (unlike the clip tool).